# Rename all files in directory based on text they contain

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to loop through all .lss files in a folder, and grab a string that exists between two tags, save that value and rename the file using that string.

Example:

```
42982934829.lss -> contains string:

<surveyls_title><![CDATA[J.3200-1118 - Project Title]]></surveyls_title>

Rename to `J.3200-1118 - Project Title.lss`
```

Here is what I have so far, but I fear my syntax is badly incorrect..

```
@Echo off
Set Folder=X:\RenameTest
Set Files=*.lss
PushD %Folder%

For %%A in (%Files%) Do For /f %%B IN (
  'findstr "<surveyls_title>.*</surveyls_title>" "%ProjectTitle%"'
    ) Do Call :Rename ..
PopD
Goto :Eof

:Rename
Echo Ren %1 "%ProjectTitle%"
```

Comment: Is the string of interest always in a single separate line? Is there always just one tag `<surveyls_title>`? May the Project Title contain brackets `[`/`]` on its own? Could the Project Title contain characters invalid for file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want.

```
@echo off
pushd "X:\RenameTest"
for %%a in (*.lss) do for /f "tokens=3*delims=[]" %%i in ('type "%%a" ^| find "</surveyls_title>"') do echo ren "%%~a" "%%~i%%~xa"
popd
```

Just remove `echo` from the line once you are happy with the printed results.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the title using Regex : [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/ANbuF2/1/)

```bat
@echo off & color 0A
Title Extract Title using Regex
Set "InputFile=42982934829.lss"
Call :Extract_Title "%InputFile%" Title
Echo %Title%
Pause & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Extract_Title <InputFile> <Title to be Set>
(
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Extract_Title(Data^)
echo Function Extract_Title(Data^)
echo      Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll  
echo      Set re = New RegExp 
echo      re.Global = True 
echo      re.IgnoreCase = True  
echo      re.Pattern = "\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]" 
echo      For Each Match in re.Execute(Data^) 
echo          Title = Match.SubMatches(0^) 
echo      Next  
echo     Extract_Title = Title
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ^< "%~1"') do set "%2=%%A"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```